# Radio button onClick=Function overwriting other functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please help me fix this sorta bug. When I check the vacation leave radio button. It will overwrite the sick leave function. Sorry for my bad english.

This is the html

```
                                             <div class="column-checkbox err-rbtn">
                                         <div class="checkbox lv-1">
                                               <label><input type="radio" class="cbselected" name="leavetype" value="" style="display:none;"></label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="checkbox lv-1">
                                               <label><input type="radio" class="cbselected" id="SL" name="leavetype" value="SL" disabled onClick="sickleavecomp();">Sick Leave</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="checkbox lv-2">
                                               <label><input type="radio" class="cbselected" id="VL" name="leavetype" value="VL" disabled onClick="vacationleavecomp();">Vacation Leave</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="checkbox lv-3">
                                               <label><input type="radio" class="cbselected" name="leavetype" value="EL" disabled onClick="">Emergency Leave</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="checkbox lv-3">
                                               <label><input type="radio" class="cbselected" name="leavetype" value="PL" disabled>Paternity Leave</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="checkbox lv-2">
                                               <label><input type="radio" class="cbselected" name="leavetype" value="ML" disabled>Maternity Leave</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="checkbox lv-3">
                                               <label><input type="radio" class="cbselected" name="leavetype" value="CL" disabled>Compasionate Leave</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="checkbox lv-3">
                                               <label><input type="radio" class="cbselected" name="leavetype" value="UL" disabled>Unpaid Leave</label>
                                            </div>
```

And this is the script I'm using.

```
 function vacationleavecomp(a) {

    $('.forvlrl').show();
    $('.vl-carryover').show();
    var vLeave = $('#u_user_blank_leave2').data('vleave');
    $('#u_user_blank_leave2').val(vLeave);

    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }
    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm
    }
    today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
    var checkcategory = $('#Category').val();
    var carryovertotal = $('#CarryOver').val();
    if (checkcategory == "Local") {
        // $('#AvailableLeave').val('15');

        // this script is for .04 per day...
        $('#datepicker').on('change', function() {
            var unval = $('#u_user_blank_leave2').val();
            var probDate = new Date($('#forcomputeleave').val());
            var nowDate = new Date($('#datepicker').val());
            var timeDiff = Math.abs(probDate.getTime() - nowDate.getTime());
            var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
            var calc = Math.round((diffDays * 0.0416666666666667) * 100) / 100;
            $('#AvailableLeave').val(calc);
            var remain = Math.round((+calc - unval) * 100) / 100;
            var remain2 = (+carryovertotal + (remain) * 100 / 100);
            var totalremain = Math.round((remain2) * 100) / 100;
            $('#Remainingleave').val(totalremain);
        });

    } else if (checkcategory == "Expat") {
        // $('#AvailableLeave').val('30');

        // this script is for .08 per day.
        $('#datepicker').on('change', function() {
            var unval = $('#u_user_blank_leave2').val();
            var probDate = new Date($('#forcomputeleave').val());
            var nowDate = new Date($('#datepicker').val());
            var timeDiff = Math.abs(probDate.getTime() - nowDate.getTime());
            var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
            var calc = Math.round((diffDays * 0.0833333333333333) * 100) / 100;
            $('#AvailableLeave').val(calc);
            var remain = Math.round((+calc - unval) * 100) / 100;
            var remain2 = (+carryovertotal + (remain) * 100 / 100);
            var totalremain = Math.round((remain2) * 100) / 100;
            $('#Remainingleave').val(totalremain) * 100 / 100;
        });
    }
}


function sickleavecomp() {

    setTimeout(vacationleavecomp, 10);
    $('.forvlrl').hide();
    $('.vl-carryover').hide();
    var sLeave = $('#u_user_blank_leave2').data('sleave');
    $('#u_user_blank_leave2').val(sLeave);
    $('#AvailableLeave').val('15');
    var avail = $('#AvailableLeave').val();
    var totalr = avail - sLeave;
    $('#Remainingleave').val(totalr);

    if (checkcategory == "Local") {
        // $('#AvailableLeave').val('15');
        // this script is for .04 per day...
        $('#datepicker').on('change', function() {

        });

    } else if (checkcategory == "Expat") {
        // $('#AvailableLeave').val('30');

        // this script is for .08 per day.
        $('#datepicker').on('change', function() {

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: you keep adding on change listeners, but never remove them .. adding an on change doesn't replace current listeners

Comment: How to remove em sir? sorry I'm quite new at programming.

Comment: I think jQuery has an `off` function that is the inverse of the `on` functions - jquery has dome [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) where you may be able to find these things

Comment: Thank you man! This really helps a lot! I just input a     $('#datepicker').off('change'); every start of the function.